# How to make angular-datatable update rows, number of results and pagination while using an observable as a data source

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I'm trying to use angular-datatables in my angular 7 application as component for displaying search results.

The request-creation-component create a search form and when a submit button is clicked a http Post request is sent to the backend using a request-service, the request-creation-component then updates an observable in the request-service which the request-result-component is subscribed to.

My problem is that the datatable used to display the results doesn't update the rows, number of results and pagination buttons when it gets new results.

The rows, number of results and pagination buttons stay the same as the first time the datatable was displayed.

The request-result-component code

```js
requestResponse;
resultsAreFound = true;
constructor(private requestService: RequestService) { }
public dataTable: DataTable;

ngOnInit() {
        this.dataTable =  {headerRow : null, footerRow: null, dataRows: null };

        this.requestService.currentSearchResult.subscribe(result => {
            this.requestResponse = result;
            if (result.length > 0) {
            this.resultsAreFound = true;
             // If it gets results, the datatable is assigned the new data. 
                this.dataTable.headerRow = Object.keys(this.requestResponse[0]);
                this.dataTable.footerRow = Object.keys(this.requestResponse[0]);
                this.dataTable.dataRows = this.requestResponse.map(function(i: { [s: string]: {}; } | ArrayLike<{}>) {
                        return Object.values(i);
                    });
            } else {
                // If it gets empty result, the datatable will be hidden and "0 results" message appears.
                this.resultsAreFound = false;
            }
         });
        }

ngAfterViewInit() {
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
            'lengthMenu': [
                [10, 25, 50, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, 'All']
            ],
            responsive: true,
            language: {
                search: '_INPUT_',
                searchPlaceholder: 'Search records',
            }
        });
```

The request-result-component template

```html
<div class="main-content" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                  <div [hidden]="resultsAreFound" class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">0 Resultats trouvées.</h4>
                  </div>
                    <div [hidden]="!resultsAreFound" class="card-body">
                        <div class="toolbar">
                        </div>
                          <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[0] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[1] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[2] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[3] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[4] }}</th>
                                      <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">{{ dataTable.headerRow[5] }}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[0] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[1] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[2] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[3] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[4] }}</th>
                                      <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[5] }}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr *ngFor="let row of dataTable.dataRows">
                                        <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
                                        <td class="text-right">
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-link btn-icon btn-sm remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end content-->
                </div>
                <!--  end card  -->
            </div>
            <!-- end col-md-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [angular-datatable](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/) ( wrapper for the datatables.net library) doesn't support dynamic data sources so when the table is created the data can't be changed.

So, to solve the problem I had to recreate the table every time the data changed.

Here's the code, the request-results.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestService } from '../services/request.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

declare var $: any;

declare interface DataTable {
    headerRow: string[];
    dataRows: string[][];
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-request-results',
    templateUrl: './request-results.component.html'
})

export class RequestResultsComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, OnInit {

@ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
dtElement: DataTableDirective;

public hideTheResults = false;
private notFirstTime = false; // if the data table is going to be used again with new data, it has to be recreated
requestResponse;
resultsAreFound = true;
dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {
    columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [4, 5] } ],
    retrieve: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    lengthMenu : [
        [10, 25, 50, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, 'All']
        ],
    responsive: true,
    language: {
    search: '_INPUT_',
    searchPlaceholder: 'Search records',
}};
dtTrigger = new Subject();
public dataTable: DataTable;

constructor(private requestService: RequestService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataTable =  {headerRow : null, footerRow: null, dataRows: null };
    this.dataTable.headerRow = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'];
    this.requestService.currentSearchResult.subscribe(result => {
        this.requestResponse = result;
        if (result.length > 0) {
            const table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
            table.destroy();
            this.resultsAreFound = true;
            if (this.notFirstTime) {
                this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
                    dtInstance.destroy();
                });
            }
            this.notFirstTime = true;
            this.dataTable.dataRows = this.requestResponse.map(
                function(i: { [s: string]: {}; } | ArrayLike<{}>) { return Object.values(i);
                });

            this.dtTrigger.next();
        } else {
            this.notFirstTime = true;
            this.resultsAreFound = false;
        }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dtTrigger.next();
}
```

and the request-results.component.html file:

```
<div class="main-content" style="margin-top: 50px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div [hidden]="resultsAreFound" class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title">0 Resultats trouvées.</h4>
            </div>
            <div [hidden]="!resultsAreFound || hideTheResults" class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Profils trouvées:</h4>
                <div class="toolbar">
                    <!--        Here you can write extra buttons/actions for the toolbar              -->
                </div>
                    <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[0] }}<span></span></th>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[1] }}<span></span></th>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[2] }}<span></span></th>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[3] }}<span></span></th>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[4] }}<span></span></th>
                                <th><span></span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[0] }}</th>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[1] }}</th>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[2] }}</th>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[3] }}</th>
                                <th>{{ dataTable.footerRow[4] }}</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let row of dataTable.dataRows">
                                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                                <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                                <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                                <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-link btn-icon btn-sm like"  href="{{row[4]}}" title="LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
            <!-- end content-->
        </div>
        <!--  end card  -->
    </div>
    <!-- end col-md-12 -->
</div>
    <!-- end row -->
```