# How to store datatable data for Next button click using Angular

Tags: javascript, datatable, angular-datatables

Trying to push row data to the array for every click, like by default loading datatable contains `300` records, if we click on Next button again 300 records should push to the array and displaying `300+ 300 = 600` records in the table. Tried below code but unable to push the data to the array. In `console.log` im getting 600 records, but table loaded only 300 records. Pls suggest me.

```
loadTable(){

let params = new HttpParams()
 let self = this;
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: "full_numbers",
      pageLength: 10,     
       stateSave: true    
    };
     dataUrl =
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json";

  this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
      this.persons = response.data;
      this.persons.forEach(f => (f.checked = false));
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  }
  getAllrecords(){
    this.persons2 = this.persons;
    this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
    this.persons1 = response.data;
    this.persons3 = this.persons1.concat(this.persons2);
    this.persons = this.persons3;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.persons));
    this.dtTrigger.next();
  });
```

}
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/push-values-to-the-array)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57165017/13579164 from this answer - The angular-datatable doesn't support dynamic data sources so when the table is created the data can't be changed. You must recreate the table.

Answer (score 0):

How I did this was with checking if we are at last page. then change next to load more. and on next click add new handler to load.

Here is sample implementation

```
DataTable = $('#tableId').DataTable({...})
DataTable.on('draw', function () {
            var info = ProductDataTable.page.info();
            if (info.page + 1 === info.pages) { // Checking if at last page
                $('#tableId_next').removeClass('disabled')
                $('#tableId_next').on('click', () => {                      
                    //fetch your data here
                    DataTable.rows.add(data).draw();
                 });

                })
                $('#productTable_next a').text("Load More");
            }
            $('#productTable_info').html('Showing ' + (info.page * info.length + 1) + '-' + ((info.page + 1) * info.length) + ` of ${info.recordsTotal} Entries.</span>' :''}`);
        });
```

after draw the (next) handler goes back to normal.